# How to exit application with home and recent apps being disabled?

Tags: android, exit, softkeys

What i want to achieve is to exit the application upon clicking on exit button in FirstActivity.
I have two activity(FirstActivity and SecondActivity).
In FirstActivity, I have got 2 buttons(launch and exit). One to get to SecondActivity and one is to exit the Application.
In SecondActivity, I have got 1 back button which is to return to FirstActivity.
So what i have done is i disabled home and recent apps soft keys in SecondActivity with this code in manifest.
I tried it out by doing the following things, in FirstActivity i clicked on the launch button to enter SecondActivity and in SecondActivity i tried home and recent apps keys and it is disabled. So i return back to FirstActivity with the back button and i clicked on exit button in FirstActivity. However, it shows this instead of closing the application. [image: 1]]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".FirstActivity ">
    </activity>
   <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity "
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**FirstActivity.java**

```
exitbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FirstActivity.this.finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to disable the "Home" and "Recent Apps" buttons when someone is *not* in your app?? That is not within the scope of an app

Comment: i only want to disable home and recent apps soft keys in SecondActivity.

Comment: There is no way to intercept the home button on Android, unless you make your app the home screen. How did you disable the home button?

Comment: yes i did make SecondActivity as my home screen.

Answer (score 1):

just say `finish()`

```
exitbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you comment `android:clearTaskOnLaunch` and try once. I'm suspecting this is the culprit.

Comment: it is still the same.

Comment: also the other two one by one. just in case

Comment: and are you sure you removed `System.exit(0);` ?

Comment: yeah i tried removing both but it is still the same and yes i did removed System.exit(0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99542/discussion-between-virus-and-dave).